# UI unresposive on a long-time for loop

Tags: c#, winforms, task

I have a WinForm Application that reads data from an excel file using Spreadsheetlight, There is a method that reads the information then do some calculation an then I create a new excel File.

The problem is that this file has about 100,000 records and I have a label in the UI that I want to update every time I read an excel row, but the label just seems unresponsive;

```
 public List<DataRow> GeExcelData(string filePath)
 {
    var myTable = new List<DataRow>();
    int row = 0;

    using (var input = new SLDocument(filePath))
    {
        SLWorksheetStatistics stats = input.GetWorksheetStatistics();
        int iStartColumnIndex = stats.StartColumnIndex;

        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = stats.EndRowIndex;
        progressBar1.Step = 1;

        for (row = stats.StartRowIndex + 1; row <= stats.EndRowIndex; ++row)
        {
            //Here is the label
            lblStatus.Text = "Reading row " + row + " of " + stats.EndRowIndex;

            var dataRowTmp = new DataRow()
            {
                name = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex),
                sku = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 1),
                value2 = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 2),
                value3 = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 3)
            };

            progressBar1.PerformStep();
            myTable.Add(dataRowTmp);
        }

        lblStatus.Text = "";
        progressBar1.Value = 0;
    }

    return myTable;
}
```

Is there a way to update the UI efficiently, while doing some long-running tasks.
Because is just a label I don't want to write some complex code.
Also I have the progressBar1 that works fine.

Comment: You need to use a background worker thread. Right now your code is running on the UI thread and therefore the UI can't update while it is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to keep your UI and data handling code separate. You can address that as well as the UI-blocking issue by using `Task` and `Progress<T>`. Unfortunately, you haven't provided a complete code example, so I don't know how you are calling this method. But I'll provide a basic template, which you can modify to suit your actual scenario, by making the assumption that the operation starts with the click of some button in your UI:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Progress<Tuple<int, int>> progress = new Progress<Tuple<int, int>>();

    progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar1.Maximum = stats.EndRowIndex;
    progressBar1.Step = 1;

    progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, progressInfo) =>
    {
        lblStatus.Text = "Reading row " + progressInfo.Item1 + " of " + progressInfo.Item2;
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
    };

    // I don't know where filePath comes form...initialize to suit your needs
    string filePath = ...;

    List<DataRow> table = await Task.Run(() => GeExcelData(filePath, progress));

    lblStatus.Text = "";
    progressBar1.Value = 0;

    // do something with table
}

public List<DataRow> GeExcelData(string filePath, IProgress<Tuple<int, int>> progress)
{
    var myTable = new List<DataRow>();
    int row = 0;

    using (var input = new SLDocument(filePath))
    {
        SLWorksheetStatistics stats = input.GetWorksheetStatistics();
        int iStartColumnIndex = stats.StartColumnIndex;

        for (row = stats.StartRowIndex + 1; row <= stats.EndRowIndex; ++row)
        {
            progress.Report(Tuple.Create(row, stats.EndRowIndex));
            var dataRowTmp = new DataRow()
            {
                name = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex),
                sku = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 1),
                value2 = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 2),
                value3 = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 3)
            };

            myTable.Add(dataRowTmp);
        }
    }

    return myTable;
}
```

The above accomplishes several things:

- It removes all UI-specific code from the method that actually does the work. This ensures better "separation of concerns", making the code simpler and easier to maintain.
- It creates a `Progress<T>` object which is used to communicate progress from the working method to the caller. Note that this progress information can be used in any variety of ways; it's not UI-specific. Doing it this way allows calling code to receive progress information and process it however they need, without making the working method have to worry about the specifics.
- The `Progress<T>` class doesn't just provide a useful shim to report progress. It includes the logic necessary to correctly invoke the progress reporting back onto the original UI thread, where UI objects can safely be used.
- It uses `await` and `Task` to actually run the working method. The `await` method will cause the `button1_Click()` method to return at that point, registering a "continuation" that represents the rest of the method. That continuation will be executed using the original IO thread when the working method finishes, assigning the result of the working method to the `table` variable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of Await and Async, it was helpfull. In the "worker" method I had to cast the progress object to IProgress to use de Report method. Also I think you misspelled the word Progress (Process) at the progress object creation. :)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Sorry for the typos...a natural consequence of browser-written code. I've edited the question to correct those issues.

Answer (score 3):

try this code, declare delegate methods that will update controls on your main thread, see the implementation below for them,

```
delegate void SetStatus(string value);
delegate void SetProgress(int value);
```

start a thread to process the data and update the controls,

```
Thread t  = new Thread(StartProc);
t.Start();


public void StartProc()
{
  using (var input = new SLDocument(filePath))
  {
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats = input.GetWorksheetStatistics();

    int iStartColumnIndex = stats.StartColumnIndex;
    for (row = stats.StartRowIndex + 1; row <= stats.EndRowIndex; ++row)
    {
        int percent = (row+1)*100/stats.EndRowIndex;
        //Here is the label
        setStatus("Reading row " + row + " of " + stats.EndRowIndex);
        var dataRowTmp = new DataRow()
        {
            name = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex),
            sku = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 1),
            value2 = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 2),
            value3 = input.GetCellValueAsString(row, iStartColumnIndex + 3)
        };
        setProgress(percent);
        myTable.Add(dataRowTmp);

    }
    setStatus("");
    setProgress(0);
  }
}
private void SetStatus(string value)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    SetStatusDelg dlg = new SetStatusDelg(this.SetStatus);
    this.Invoke(value);
    return;
  }
  lblStatus.Text = value;
}
private void SetProgress(int value)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    SetProgressDelg dlg = new SetProgressDelg(this.SetStatus);
    this.Invoke(value);
    return;
  }
  progressBar1.value = value;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to do all of that explicit invoking. Either use `BackgroundWorker` (older idiomatic API with cross-thread invoking support built in) or `Task` and `Progress<T>` (new idiomatic API with cross-thread invoking support built in). And even if one does insist on doing everything manually: there is no need to check `InvokeRequired`, because you _know_ it is; and there is no need to create all new delegate types when `Action<string>` and `Action<int>` work just as well.

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  I know this logic works because I use it all the time, the only thing I would do is to call the methods that update the controls once every 1000 to several thousands records.  I tried to use Task to replace this logic and never managed to make it work correctly.  I will look into backgroundworker, I never used it before. thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I agree the above should work. But it's really not the right way to do this. The whole point of using a framework like .NET is that you _don't_ have to reinvent the wheel all the time. The above is pretty much _all_ about reinventing the wheel. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform the processing on a background thread and update the label with progress information until it finishes. Try creating a BackgroundThread instance and then perform the loop inside the thread processing. In order to get the progress label updated you can pass in a SynchronizationContext and use that to post back a call for the update on the UI thread.

Comment: There is no need to pass a `SynchronizationContext` when using `BackgroundWorker`. That's the whole point of using `BackgroundWorker`!

Comment: You cannot update the progress bar from the background worker unless you use a mechanism to ensure the update occurs back on the UI thread.

Comment: That mechanism is built into `BackgroundWorker`, via the `ProgressChanged` event. Again, that's _why_ one uses `BackgroundWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick to update the label value.

`lblStatus.Refresh();`

Although, I would prefer it to be done on a background thread.

Comment: Using `Refresh()` serves only to cover up the larger problem: the UI thread is completely blocked. It will update the label, but the program will otherwise remain unresponsive, which is a huge flaw in a GUI program.

Comment: By going through his  question, you will realise that he just wants the label text to get updated so that user has an impression that some work is going on.This answers his question for label unresponsiveness. The correct way is of course using a background thread to perform such tasks. @PeterDuniho

Comment: Thanks it works, but now I know that I'm avoiding te real problem.